# jQuizMe modifications to Game End

Tags: jquery

For those who are familiar with JQuizMe, I am having an issue. I want to add a message and a link on the end screen when a user has completed the quiz and has got 100% of the questions correct.

http://code.google.com/p/jquizme/

Demo:http://www.bateru.com/jquery/jquizme2.1/demo/Chemistry-Quiz.html

Any ideas?
I thought it would be easy enough for a novice like me...but apparently not

EDIT:
Worked it out - it was in the options, but the example provided was not quite right. This works:

```
  options.statusUpdate = function( quizInfo, $quiz ){

        if( quizInfo.hasQuit ){
            var response = ( quizInfo.score >= 99 ) ? "Good job!" : "You need help." ;
            $( $quiz ).find( ".q-statDetails" ).hide();
            $( $quiz ).find( ".q-extraStat" ).html( response );
        }


    };
```

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/CRNHe.png i got 100 % :)

Comment: :) but how do I display a message.."Congrats you are awesome!"